# within-group calculation of data.frame in R

Tags: r

In my input data.frame `df.in` I would like to add a group-column that should be either High or Low, based on the following criteria:
High: If the median `Expression` within each `Patient` is higher that 0
Low: If the median `Expression` within each `Patient` is equal to 0

My problem is how to define that the median should be calculated within the `Patient`

df.in

```
  Expression    Cell Patient
       0.00 MM02_48    MM01
       3.00 MM02_50    MM01
       1.00 MM02_51    MM02
       1.79  MM02_5    MM02
       0.00 MM02_61    MM03
       0.00 MM02_72    MM03
```

df.out

```
  Expression    Cell Patient Group
       0.00 MM02_48    MM01 High
       3.00 MM02_50    MM01 High
       1.00 MM02_51    MM02 High
       1.79  MM02_5    MM02 High
       0.00 MM02_61    MM03 Low
       0.00 MM02_72    MM03 Low
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `dplyr`.

You can use `group_by` to calculate the median by Patient and use and `ifelse` statement in  `mutate` to assign `High` or `Low` based on the median value of Expression.

```
library(dplyr)

Expression <- c(0.00, 3.00, 1.00, 1.79, 0.00, 0.00)
Cell <- c("MM02_48", "MM02_50", "MM02_51", "MM02_5", "MM02_61", "MM02_72")
Patient <- c("MM01", "MM01", "MM02", "MM02", "MM03", "MM03")


df <- as_tibble(cbind(Expression, Cell, Patient))
df$Expression <- as.numeric(Expression)

df %>% group_by(Patient) %>% mutate(Group = ifelse(median(Expression) >= 1, "High", "Low"))

      Expression Cell    Patient Group
         <dbl>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
    1       0    MM02_48 MM01    High 
    2       3    MM02_50 MM01    High 
    3       1    MM02_51 MM02    High 
    4       1.79 MM02_5  MM02    High 
    5       0    MM02_61 MM03    Low  
    6       0    MM02_72 MM03    Low
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at how to use `data.table`, it's very useful for this kind of operation.

In your case, this can be dne as follows :

```
library(data.table)

# make dummy data
x <- data.frame(expr = rnorm(20), pat = rep(letters[1:5], each=4))
x <- as.data.table(x)

x[, ("group"):= ifelse(median(expr) > 0, "high", "low"), pat]
x
```

data.table uses a `DT[i, j, by]` schema.

`("group"):=...` s the 'j', and defines a new column from the expression after.

`,pat]` indicates the expression is evaluated wihin each level of `pat`